# Optimization issue

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, compiler-optimization

I'm developing a controller program used to run a humanoid kidsize robot. The OS is debian 6 and whole programs are written in C++11. CPU is a 1GHz VorteX86 SD and its architecture is Intel i486.

I need to compile my code with maximum possible optimization. currently I'm using gcc with 3rd level optimization flag and i486 optimization tunning:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O3 -march=i486 -mtunes=i486
```

I'm wondering if its possible to gain more optimized code or not. I searched around about optimization flags and compiler benchmarks, but didn't find any...

My question is which compiler for C++ is generates faster code? Specially for i486 architecture.

Current candidates are: ICC XE, GCC 4.6, EkoPath

Comment: Have you tried any? Given such a specific set of requirements, your best bet is probably to set up a suitable test harness and benchmark each of the options.

Comment: Why do you need faster code?  Are you trying to implement real-time control?  Normally a microcontroller with deterministic behavior is used for something like that, but if you want to use Linux, [RTwiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/articles/f/r/e/Frequently_Asked_Questions_7407.html) might be a good source.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Xenomai rt kernel, though image processing algorithms and decision mechanism should be really fast.

Comment: Before paying for ICC, I would like to see some benchmarks or success stories...

Comment: The Vortex86 SD is apparently a i586 without FPU. Try compiling for 586 instead, that may help quite a bit. Perhaps GCC has a specific setting for it, if so use that instead. You don't want it to optimize for U/V pipelines after all :-)

Comment: No it's really i486! The datasheet says i586 but after weeks of trying, we considered that there is no support for i586.

Comment: `-march=native` is what I'd prefer.

Comment: You can trial ICC without buying: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/Intel-C-Compiler-for-Windows.shtml

Comment: Check out some of these optimization links:  
[Optimization discussion][1]  
[Another optimization discussion][2]  
[Optimizing with processor cache][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932515/effective-optimization-strategies-on-modern-c-compilers/2932815#2932815
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074099/coding-practices-which-enable-the-compiler-optimizer-to-make-a-faster-program/2075264#2075264
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029738/algorithms-for-modern-hardware/3029763#3029763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options). There are too many permutations to test them all; maybe give Acovea a try, which tests for the best one with a genetic approach.

If you have many floating points optimizations, you may try `-ffast-math` or `-Ofast`, which includes `-ffast-math`. However, you lose IEEE floating math compliance.

Comment: there is no hardware FPU in this CPU; only soft-fpu from linux kernel.

Comment: @osgx: But the soft-fpu can be used for IEEE-correct-FPU calculations, too, not? fast-math is about applying optimizations that break IEEE-compatibility, e.g. operand reordering or strength reduction (e.g. replacing `x * 3` with `x + x + x`).

Comment: Yes, -ffast math will emit more optimal code; but soft-fpu is too slow in any case.

Answer (score 2):

An option which typically makes the code faster is -funroll-loops